# MySql optimizate query . JOIN with same table multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

The task is to take the posts to which the user is subscribed. It can be signed either for the car or for the user. type 1 -> sub on user. type 0 -> sub on car

My subscription table :
[subscription table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tmnd.png)

cars_posts table:
[cars posts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wsZn.png)

indexes cars_posts table
[indexes cars_posts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D71jy.png)

I have this query :

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
    (p.id) AS id,
    p.title,
    p.categoryId,
    p.content,
    p.userId,
    p.createdAt,
    p.mileage,
    p.costAmount,
    p.costCurrency,
    p.coverUrl
FROM cars_posts as p
LEFT JOIN subscription as s1 ON s1.subId = p.userId
LEFT JOIN subscription as s2 ON s2.subId = p.carId
WHERE (s2.userId = 37 AND s2.type = 0) OR (s1.userId = 37 AND s1.type = 1)
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.id DESC;
```

but on EXPLAIN i have :
[EXPLAIN ANSWER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvutt.png)

For this query (this query returned all cars posts) :

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
    (p.id) AS id,
    p.title,
    p.categoryId,
    p.content,
    p.userId,
    p.createdAt,
    p.mileage,
    p.costAmount,
    p.costCurrency,
    p.coverUrl
FROM cars_posts as p
LEFT JOIN subscription as s1 ON s1.subId = p.userId AND s1.type = 1 AND s1.userId = 37
LEFT JOIN subscription as s2 ON s2.subId = p.carId AND s2.type = 0 AND s2.userId = 37
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.id DESC;
```

i have explain answer:
[second explain answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFK4Q.png)

for some reason the index search does not work. Tell me how to correctly make a request so that the search is based on indexes

Comment: The performance of these queries depends on the correct index on your `subscription` table.  Please [edit] your question to show that. And, the second query won't even begin to work correctly unless you change the `LEFT JOIN`s to ordinary inner `JOIN`s.

Comment: @O.Jones you can see my subscription table and indexes on my question. Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tmnd.png
Can you help me create correctly query please?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating this index on your `subscription` table. It is a [covering index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index) for your queries.

```sql
CREATE INDEX user_type_sub ON subscription 
       (userId, type, subId);
```

Comment: i created this index. but i have problem ( i think). when i use count for subscription table i have 301 
On indexes i have : 299 rows. I think it's not okay.

Comment: https://ibb.co/1rZpqCs (link for table with index). Why type can be 299? and subId. It's not okay (when table have 301 rows)